# How i add tabs in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

this is my panel,i want to add tabs in this panel.I tried so many example from here but not success..
here is my code.

```
this.Tab = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'PG Routing',
        //iconCls:'mrc',
        layout:'border',
        border:false,
        width:1000,
            height:600,
        closable:true,
        id:'pgrouting_tab',
        items:[this.addnewchannelform]     
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use the [Ext.tab.Panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel) instead of Ext.Panel. Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/js95syuv/1/) example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Foo'
        },
        {
            title: 'Bar',
            tabConfig: {
                title: 'Custom Title',
                tooltip: 'A button tooltip'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```